# I want to run code of a older version of matlab in latest version of matlab?

Tags: matlab

Hi I'm in a great trouble
 I have a wavelet transform code for image processing in a an older version of matlab which uses older functions, not supported in new matlab version i.e mmread() etc. is there any tool or anything which can help me converting or running this code??? thank you very much

Comment: are you sure this is to do with backward compatibility? [imread](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html) is documented in Matlab 2012a, and to my knowledge still exists in 2012b. Perhaps your problem is that you don't have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: sorry i wanted to know about mmread(), in new version it is mmreader()

Answer (score 4):

When there's a rare incompatible change in furnctions in Matlab, the solution is to modify the code to use the new functions. If you want to ensure that your code will still run on the old versions of Matlab as well, then you can use `verlessthan`:

```
if verLessThan('matlab', '7.0.1')
% -- Put code to run under MATLAB 7.0.0 and earlier here --
else
% -- Put code to run under MATLAB 7.0.1 and later here --
end
```

Comment: @ElmarZander: Matlab has been very good in maintaining backward compatibility in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a license for MATLAB that is in maintenance, you can download previous versions of MATLAB from MathWorks website.